# catch the winning slide content

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am creating a wheel spinner game using reactJS.
while it is running correctly but how can I catch that slide content where the timer stops just below the pointer?

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-framework-71qvd

[image]

Comment: you can use the IntersectionObserver API

Comment: @AngelSalazar, can you please show me how by editing my code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` on Arrow and `<li>` element to check if the arrow is above the element.

Here is a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-smoke-jp1s6

function that checks if elements are overlapping:

```
areOverlapping = (rect1, rect2) => {
    return (
      rect2.top <= rect1.top &&
      rect1.top <= rect2.bottom &&
      (rect2.top <= rect1.bottom && rect1.bottom <= rect2.bottom) &&
      (rect2.left <= rect1.left && rect1.left <= rect2.right) &&
      (rect2.left <= rect1.right && rect1.right <= rect2.right)
    );
  };
```

Comment: how are you calling this method? can you please also share your code editor link.

Comment: I edited the comment with the new link. Getting the element overlapping is a bit tricky because the `<li>` is rotated

Comment: I have tried to merge the code https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-framework-71qvd with the dynamic data but in that case how to deal with ref. can you please look in the link..